# Linking a modal to an entry field and validating using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

With the following code I'm trying to validate an entry field in JavaScript. The validation requires only 10 characters. When you authenticate, it is supposed to display a modal with a confirmation message:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var con_code, text;
  //getting the field 
  con_code = document.getElementById("con_code").value;

  if ($.trim($('con_code').val()).length == 0) {
    text = "Authentication code is not valid";
  }
  //trigger to the modal if it meets the condition
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#con_code").click(function() {
      $("#myModal").modal();
    });
  });

  document.getElementById("error_con_code").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Confirmation Code.</label>
    <input type="text" name="con_code" id="con_code" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter your Confirmation Code" />

    <br> //the error code display

    <span id="error_con_code" class="text-danger"></span>

    <br> //the authenticate button
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="con_code" onclick="myFunction()">Authenticate</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> //the modal
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

However, it is not authenticating the confirm code. How can I fix it?

Comment: What "problem" are you talking about because you haven't told us. Is it not validating 10 chars? Does the message not appear?

Comment: Your code also only handles the case where no authentication code is supplied. What happens the rest of the time?

Comment: The problem is; I am supposed to enter any code with 10 characters to test whether it will validate the entry after which it should display a modal when you click the Authenticate button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error at: 
if($.trim($('con_code').val()).length ==0){...}. 
It should be $('#con_code')

Also you have 2 elements with the same id="con_code".

Please check with the following codes.
I am assuming you want to show the modal when there is 10 chars in the input field. If the rule changes, then please edit at: 'if ($.trim(con_code.val()).length != 10) {}' in the below codes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    $("#con_code_btn").click(function() {
        var con_code = $('#con_code');
        var error_con_code = $('#error_con_code');

        error_con_code.html('');// Remove Previous Error Message(if any);

        if ($.trim(con_code.val()).length != 10) {
            error_con_code.html("entication code is not valid");
        }
        else {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    });
}
```

Also please change the id of the button to "con_code_btn" in the form:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="con_code_btn" onclick="myFunction()">Authenticate</button>
```

Comment: where should i change

Comment: I have edited the answer and added example codes. Please check again.